# No emojis are shown in the vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I think since the last update of Visual Studio Code (v 1.31), I don't see uncide emojis in the vscode terminal.

That means, when I try to `console.log` for example "", it gives me the following output: "�".

```
console.log() // -> returns � in the console
```

[image: Preview how the output looks for me]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Console parse text as only string

Comment: @ZainFarooq So why did it work before the update?

Comment: Hmm, Why do you want this in your console?

Comment: because I need to know which emoji it is @ZainFarooq

Comment: Hmm, But you can simply embed your code in `p` tag

Comment: This is a nodejs application @ZainFarooq

Comment: Is this fixed in v1.43? see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#unicode-11-support  Perhaps it helped?

Comment: No it's not fixed

Comment: Any insight? It looks really bad...

Comment: What shell is this and what OS are you on? If this is windows, check what the codepage is by running the `chcp.com` command.

Comment: Still happening in Visual Code terminal:

Version: 1.82.2 (user setup)
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621